# Microsoft Graph v1.0 - Convert to other formats - pptm not supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

According to the documentation of the microsoft graph v1.0 api it is possible to convert a pptm file to a pdf file. [See](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
When I call the API a get a 406 - not supported response (InputFormatNotSupported).
This happens with the sdk and via a basic rest call.
For example:

```
let pdf = await client.api('/me/drive/items/{item-id}/content?format=pdf').get();
```

```
let response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/content?format=pdf');
```

I have seen that in the new beta version pptm is not supported any more. Hope it will be still supported because this is a typical use case for me.
Does anybody can help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the link in your question to Microsoft docs pptm is included in the supported source extensions.